# Mixing browser viewport widths

Tags: css, responsive-design, viewport

I'm working on a project where we are looking to deploy a responsive mobile version of a website for a client - in this scenario the existing 'desktop' site has two breakpoints:

```
>= 980px
>= 1200px
```

On devices with screens smaller than 980px the 'small desktop' site is just scaled to fit the browser so users are able to tap to zoom etc and effectively navigate the full desktop site.

We now want to implement a version of the site for small screens (<480px), however the problem I have encountered is that by changing the meta viewport tag to accommodate a breakpoint for a 1:1 layout on small screens I've lost the ability for users with screens between 481px and 979px to use a scaled version of the desktop site.

Previously I was using the meta tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=980">`

But as I understand it to have small screen devices scale the layout correctly I need to adjust that to read:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

What I really need of course is a mixture of both! - Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see a way around that as you're trying to adopt both a fixed and responsive site for different viewport sizes. If you have 2 large breakpoints and now a smaller breakpoint targeted at mobile then your best bet may be to make a breakpoint for 481+ up to 980.

Comment: I don't think it will solve anything but out of interest how does it behave if you remove `initial-scale=1.0"` from your meta tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had a similar challenge with http://blakelondon.co.uk - native scaling on devices larger than mobile, than responsive on mobile.

Your issue is the reverse of mine but I think the same approach would work.

The solution uses JavaScript to rewrite the meta-viewport to a fixed width to force native device scaling. Caveat - it comes with the very minor drawback of a layout reflow in one of the contexts.

First set the meta-viewport as normal:

```
<meta name=“viewport” content=“width=device-width” />
```

Then, sprinkle in some JavaScript to rewrite this value to a fixed width to force native scaling on smaller devices (pick screen.width to suit):

```
if (screen.width <= 640) {
  viewport = document.querySelector(“meta[name=viewport]”);
  viewport.setAttribute(‘content’, ‘width=980’);
}
```

Hope that helps!

P.S. My colleague @cole007 also broached this issue, with slightly different code:
http://cole007.net/blog/136/responsiveish-viewport-hack

Comment: Haven't tried this but I guess to avoid the visible reflow on mobile I could set the body to opacity: 0 in the CSS for <480 and then do a fade in using JavaScript on completion of load (or something like that). But I digress - thanks for the excellent solution and the link to the blog post. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. I would ensure it is used in conjunction with html.js class to ensure non-JS visitors don't suffer. And you're welcome :)

Comment: Not sure that would work if opacity: 0 was set in the CSS so yea may not be a great idea but I don't recall if you can disable JS in mobile Safari etc anyway...